# Why is my if statement always false?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I run this script:

```
if (Copy-Item .\test.ps1 $env:SystemRoot\System32)
{
    Write-Host "Done."
    exit 0
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Not done."
    Write-Host "You must be root."
    exit 1
}
```

When I run this script as a normal user I got the message in `else` statement, because I am not root. And this is okay.

But I run this script as root I also got the message in `else` statement! But file copy operation is succeded. I can't get the message in `if` statement. Why?

I also check the error code and its always `False`.

Comment: As an alternative to checking for success or failure, you can check for administrator before attempting to run the other code. I use `if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) { Write-Error 'Please run as administrator'; exit }`

Comment: @RichardRobertson another alternative to this would be to add `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` at the start of your script, then the whole script would only run if you are admin

Answer (score 82, accepted):

An `if` statement does not evaluate whether the command inside its condition ran successfully. It will only check the value (in your case the return of your command) and cast it to a `bool`.

[`Copy-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7) does not return anything by default, and that's why your `if` statement is always `false`, because `[bool]$null` is `$false`.

You have three options here:

Add the [`-PassThru`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects/) parameter to get some form of return:

```
if (Copy-Item .\test.ps1 $env:SystemRoot\System32 -PassThru)
```

Use the [`$?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634115/what-is-in-powershell/10634171) variable to see if your previous command was successful:

```
Copy-Item .\test.ps1 $env:SystemRoot\System32
if ($?) {
    Write-Host "Done."
    exit 0
}
else {
    Write-Host "Not done."
    Write-Host "You must be root."
    exit 1
}
```

However, the most reliable way would be to wrap it in [`Try {} Catch {}`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7) and add [`-ErrorAction Stop`](https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/20867/erroraction-parameter)

```
Try {
    Copy-Item .\test.ps1 $env:SystemRoot\System32 -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Done."
    exit 0
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Not done."
    Write-Host "You must be root."
    exit 1
}
```